# function that makes another function only executable once in JS

Tags: javascript

I have been working to create a function that given another function will make that second function only callable once. not unlike the `_.once()` function.

the desired outcome is the following:

```
const oneTimeFunction = _.once(function(string) { string.split(''); })

oneTimeFunction('hello')

//returns: 'olleh', and if called again it would have no effect returning the same thing a the original call.
```

Currently this is what I have:

```
_.once = function (func) {
  var called = 0;
  let args = null;

  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
  }

  return function () {
    if (called === 0) {
      console.log('being called');
      called ++;

      if (!args) {
        console.log('without apply');
        return func.call(arguments);
      } else {
        console.log('with apply');
        return func.apply(this,args);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('this has been called');
      return null;
    }
  }; 
};
```

I am running into a wall as it is returning error type undefined even with everything I have tried. Any help, even to get to where it can call the function regardless of the one time only stipulation? Thanks!

Comment: One thing is that you are doing arguments processing at the wrong place. You are processing the arguments to `.once()` instead of the arguments of `function(string)...`

Comment: Ah! that makes sense because the arguments of function(string) are a level deeper. I  have created a simpler version of this that just gets the function(string) to work, but cannot get it to only be called once.

Comment: I now have started with this version that is doing the basic job of running the passed in `func`.  I will try to add the one time functionality next.

`_.once = function (func) {
  console.log(typeof func);
  let oneTimer = func;
  return (function inner () {
    return oneTimer;
  })();
};`

Comment: Have you looked at the lodash source to study how it works? https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/once.js which simply calls `before(2, function)` https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/before.js Of course make changes as needed, but that will give you a good base to start from.

Answer (score 1):

create a variable that count how much this function is called

```
let count = 0;
function once(str) {

  if(count < 1){
      count++;
      return str.split("").reverse().join("");
  }
  else return str;
}

console.log(once("hello")); // olleh
console.log(once("hello")); // hello
console.log(once("hello")); // hello
```

Comment: This does not meet the specification that OP has made because subsequent calls return the argument's value, not the original call's value. `"and if called again it would have no effect returning the same thing a the original call"`. Also, this is supposed to be a wrapper function, not a function with hardcoded string manipulation

Comment: Yeah thanks, but it works for me, the same as the output that I wrote, I know there's a code more readable and more useful than my!

Comment: If you call it once with `"hello"`, every subsequent call has to return `"olleh"`, no matter what input. It's not supposed to echo the input after the first call

Answer (score 1):

In reading your question, I'm seeing that you would like to always return the first value on subsequent calls:

"if called again it would have no effect returning the same thing a[s] the original call."

So I believe you want to do something like this:

```
function computeOnce(myFn) {
  let origVal = undefined;

  return function (...args) {
    // if this is not set, this is the first call
    if (!origVal) {
      // execute the function and store it's return value
      origVal = myFn(...args);
    }
    return origVal;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch -- I missed the bit about returning the same value.